# "Поэтому не стесняйтесь(?) пишите!" — какой знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**Поэтому не стесняйтесь(?) пишите!**
Запятая или тире необходимы после слова "стесняйтесь"?

Comment: В начале фразы не стесняйтесь, — пишите прописную!

Answer (score 1):

Пример, который вы приводите, можно охарактеризовать как сложное бессоюзное предложение, части которого выражены определенно-личными предложениями.

По правилам, в бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится тире: 1) **если между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения устанавливаются сопоставительные и противительные отношения...** 2) **если во второй части предложения заключено указание на результат, следствие" (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2011. С. 263).**

Постановка тире оправдана и том случае, если рассматривать ваш пример как простое прдложение. с однородными скауемыми, ср.: "между однородными членами предложения ставится тире... при пропуске противительного союза" (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. **Полный академический справочник. М., 2011. С. 193). В данном случае можно предположить пропуск противительного (сопоставительного) союза а:  не стесняйтесь, (а) пишите.**

Comment: Разве у нас сложноподчиненное предложение?

Comment: @М_Г, а где речь идет о СПП?

Comment: Ответ был изменен, а в первоначальном варианте упоминалось СПП.

Answer (score 0):

**Поэтому не стесняйтесь, пишите!**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Он еще раз напомнил, что ждет от меня записей из детства, юношеских лет, ― **не стесняйтесь, пишите** всё как было. [Геннадий Николаев. Вещие сны тихого психа // «Звезда», 2002]

Ради бога, **не стесняйтесь, пишите** мне тогда, когда Вам этого хочется и когда Вы будете чувствовать влечение к беседе со мной. [П. И. Чайковский. Письма Н. Ф. фон-Мекк (1878)]